# Reduce list of word, count tuples up to aggregate key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to take the Spark word count example and aggregate word counts by some other value (for example, words and counts by person where person is "VI" or "MO" in the case below)

I have an rdd which is a list of tuples whose values are lists of tuples:

```
from operator import add
reduced_tokens = tokenized.reduceByKey(add)
reduced_tokens.take(2)
```

Which gives me:

```
[(u'VI', [(u'word1', 1), (u'word2', 1), (u'word3', 1)]),
 (u'MO',
  [(u'word4', 1),
   (u'word4', 1),
   (u'word5', 1),
   (u'word8', 1),
   (u'word10', 1),
   (u'word1', 1),
   (u'word4', 1),
   (u'word6', 1),
   (u'word9', 1),
   ...
 )]
```

I want something like:

```
[
 ('VI', 
    [(u'word1', 1), (u'word2', 1), (u'word3', 1)],
 ('MO', 
    [(u'word4', 58), (u'word8', 2), (u'word9', 23) ...)
]
```

Similar to the [word count example here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_develop_run.html), I would like to be able to filter out words with a count below some threshold for some person. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys that you're trying to reduce across are `(name, word)` pairs, not just names. So you need to do a `.map` step to fix-up your data:

```
def key_by_name_word(record):
  name, (word, count) = record
  return (name, word), count

tokenized_by_name_word = tokenized.map(key_by_name_word)
counts_by_name_word = tokenized_by_name_word.reduce(add)
```

This should give you

```
[
  (('VI', 'word1'), 1),
  (('VI', 'word2'), 1),
  (('VI', 'word3'), 1),
  (('MO', 'word4'), 58),
  ...
]
```

To get it into exactly the same format you mentioned, you can then do:

```
def key_by_name(record):
  # this is the inverse of key_by_name_word
  (name, word), count = record
  return name, (word, count)

output = counts_by_name_word.map(key_by_name).reduceByKey(add)
```

But it might actually be easier to work with the data in the flat format that `counts_by_name_word` is in.

Comment: My data was structured a little differently but this helped me to understand how to fix it. My initial data looked like `[Row(key=u'VI', item=u'word1 word2 word3'), ...]` and I created a function that tokenized the item and returned `[((name, token), 1) for token in tokens]`. From there I applied the function to my data with flatMap to get the structure you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is how I solved each part of the question:

**Ask 1: Aggregate word counts by some key**

```
import re

def restructure_data(name_and_freetext):
    name = name_and_freetext[0]
    tokens = re.sub('[&|/|\d{4}|\.|\,|\:|\-|\(|\)|\+|\$|\!]', ' ', name_and_freetext[1]).split()
    return [((name, token), 1) for token in tokens]

filtered_data = data.filter((data.flag==1)).select('name', 'item')
tokenized = filtered_data.rdd.flatMap(restructure_data)
```

**Ask 2: Filter out words with a count below some threshold:**

```
from operator import add

# keep words which have counts >= 5
counts_by_state_word = tokenized.reduceByKey(add).filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 5)

# map filtered word counts into a list by key so we can sort them
restruct = counts_by_name_word.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], [(x[0][1], x[1])]))
```

**Bonus: Sort words from most frequent to least frequent**

```
# sort the word counts from most frequent to least frequent words
output = restruct.reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: (x[0], sorted(x[1], key=lambda y: y[1], reverse=True))).collect()
```